# select the immediate parent element of an iframe from the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the markup below:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="aaa"></div>
        <div class="aaa"></div>
        <div class="aaa">
            <iframe>
                <form id="myform">

                </form>
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="aaa"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On loading the `iframe`, it contains the form '#myform'.
Upon submission of the form, I need to run a certain callback based on the `div.aaa` that is the immediate parent of the `iframe`.

Any solution based on `parent.document` cannot help me much, since I do not know the ID of the `div.aaa`.

What I'd like to do is something like `$('#myform').closest('div.aaa')`, but, of course, this fails because any element beyond the `iframe` window itself cannot be accessed in this fashion.

How can I best access this iframe's immediate parent `div`, which is actually an element in it's parent document?

Both `parent` and `iframe` are of same origin.

Comment: Will there be multiple iframes or just the one?

Comment: @charlietfl apologies for the time lapse. Indeed, there might be multiple iframes, each one nesting the next one. That being said, half a loaf is better than none. Therefore if there's a one-iframe solution, let's have it!

Comment: OK so my answer and demo work for multiple iframes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can jump up to the parent window and look for specific iframe in parent document by matching frame element contentWindow to known window inside the iframe

Something like:

```
$(window.parent.document).find('iframe').filter(function() {
  return this.contentWindow === window;
}).parent().doSomething()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSU7crIRkVubpD1faiME?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl for your answer and the DEMO. Using the snippet above, the `.parent()` actually fetches the `div.aaa` of the parent. However, for whatever reason, previously applied `data()` values cannot be retrieved out of it. Other attributes are available but not `.data()` values. Is this a known limitation or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure why and don't see any reason it wouldn't work. Can you update my demo with a more real world case that matches yours?

Comment: I have updated your demo, applying and attribute and a data parameter each. Indeed, the former seems to work just fine, but not the latter!

Comment: Link to the forked version?

Comment: That is a bit strange. Seems that jQuery doesn't store set data using Element.dataset and must be storing it internally in the global jQuery object. Here's a workaround that uses the parent window version of jQuery http://next.plnkr.co/edit/QgPM7DJRNHv4hefu

Comment: Basically I changed to `window.parent.$('iframe').filter...` and it picks up the `data()` you set on targetDiv in the parent window

Comment: Many thanks @charlietfl for your help on this question. I'm struggling with something related: Why is it that using ESC key to close nested dialogs does NOT work whenever the dialog contains an iframe that has the current focus? Again, any way around this? I know I should be asking this question anew, but...

Comment: Probably because focus is on iframe and events in iframe are in an insulated window and don't bubble to parent

Comment: Because jQuery Dialog is so widely known and used, and because sequentially closing nested dialogs with ESC is THE intuitive thing to expect, I was expecting that this known limitation would have some sort of workaround. Any workaround anyone?

Answer (score -5):

I would recommend to use `.closest('.aaa')`. But if you could assign a unique identifier you may use `.parent('.uniq_selector')` that is a bit more performant.

Comment: It is not that simple to traverse out of an iframe window